# Font Awesome Accessibility

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, font-awesome

I have been using Font Awesome and according to their accessibility docs,
If your icon has semantic meaning, all you need to do is throw a title="meaning" attribute.
Auto-accessibility takes care of the rest, adding the following:

Proper ARIA role (role="img")
title tag with a proper id attribute
aria-labelledby attribute and wire it to the title tag.

But I tried it and it does not add aria-labelledby
And on testing with Site Improve, it throws error saying icon does not have alt text. How do I fix this?
working Code below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/40v5jk6no7

Code here

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
import FontAwesomeIcon from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import faCalendar from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular/faCalendar";
import faSquare from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular/faSquare";
import solid from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid";

fontawesome.config = {
  familyPrefix: "far"
};

fontawesome.library.add(faCalendar, faSquare);

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
    Favorite calendar: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="calendar" title="magic" />
    Icon from regular: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["far", "calendar"]} />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You might need to add a React tag so people who know how it works will find the question.

Comment: do you even need to label your icons? from your example, it looks like you can just wrap then in a `<span aria-hidden="true" />`. Unless they provide value, i'd just ignore them.